# Generate Meta last-modified in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, meta

I use ASP.NET, and I want generate **Meta tags** for **last-modified**:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="2013-10-23@17:23:00 UTC" />
</head>
```

I use this code in the page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack) return;


        // .. and set last modified in the date format specified in the HTTP rfc.
        //  <meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="2013-10-23@17:23:00 UTC" />
        var value = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R");
        Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", value);
        Response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", value);

        Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
    }
```

But nothing generate in the **head**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `HtmlMeta` Control.

```
HtmlMeta hm = new HtmlMeta();
hm.Name = "Last-Modified";
hm.Content = value;
Page.Header.Controls.Add(hm);
```